# Collect feedback data in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

What is the best way to collect feedback data (feature request or bug report) in flutter app? I dont want to connect my app to firestore or publicize my email.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about you build an online form on something like Google Forms, and then just send people in your app to the form?